# How can I fix an error when removing & adding an OpenLayers Heatmap layer?

Tags: javascript, webgl, openlayers, heatmap

I would like to toggle the visibility of the heatmap layer.

When I press the toggle button the first time, the heatmap layer is correctly hidden.

However, when I press the toggle button the second time, the follow two errors appear in the console:

```
index.html:1 [.WebGL-0x12001b3e300] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Insufficient buffer size.
index.html:1 [.WebGL-0x12001b3e300] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Insufficient buffer size.
```

I figure something is not being cleaned up correctly with the heatmap when the layer is removed. Is this a bug?

Regardless, what can I do to work around or fix this issue?

```js
const osm = new ol.source.OSM();

osm.setTileGridForProjection(
  "EPSG:4326",
  ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({ extent: [-180, -90, 180, 90] })
);

const outageSource = new ol.source.Vector();

const heatmapLayer = new ol.layer.Heatmap({
  source: outageSource,
  blur: 20,
  radius: 20,
  zIndex: 10,
  weight: function (feature) {
    return feature.get("weight");;
  },
});

const feature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point([-77.0231007567732604, 38.902979974562264]),
  weight: 1
});

outageSource.addFeature(feature);

const tileLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({ source: osm });

const map = new ol.Map({
  target: "map",
  layers: [tileLayer, heatmapLayer],
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: "EPSG:4326",
    center: [-77.0231007567732604, 38.902979974562264],
    zoom: 18
  })
});

ol.proj.get("EPSG:4326").setExtent([-180, -85, 180, 85]);

let visible = true;

function toggleHeatmap() {
  if (visible) {
    map.removeLayer(heatmapLayer);
  } else {
    map.addLayer(heatmapLayer);
  }

  visible = !visible;
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.3.0/ol.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.3.0/dist/ol.min.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
<button onclick="toggleHeatmap();">Toggle Heatmap</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding a removing the layer you could use

```
function toggleHeatmap() {
  visible = !visible;
  heatmapLayer.setVisible(visible);
}
```